# How to structure factor variable spread in many columns

Tags: r

I have data collected from a survey. One factor variable is like this:

```
Column1  Column2  Column3  Column4  Column5
A        B        C
B        C
A        B        C        D        E
A        C        E
C        E
B        D        E
```

In other words, classes are spread in many different variables. I want to create one binary variable (1 or 0) for each class (A, B, C, D, E). However it's not clear to me how to do it. How can I do it?

EDIT

The output would be something like this:

```
A      B      C      D      E
1      1      1      0      0
0      1      1      0      0
1      1      1      1      1
1      0      1      0      1
0      0      1      0      1
0      1      0      1      1
```

Comment: If you provide the output of what you want this to look like your question will be more understandable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
> data <- data.frame(Column1=c("A","B","A"),Column2=c("B","A","A"))
> data
  Column1 Column2
1       A       B
2       B       A
3       A       A
> f <- unique(unlist(data))
> tb <- data.frame(sapply(f, function(x) (rowSums(data == as.character(x)) != 0)*1))
> names(tb) <- f
> tb
  A B
1 1 1
2 1 1
3 1 0
```

Comment: I prefer `f <- as.character(unique(unlist(data))); tmpf <- function(x) as.numeric(apply(data==x,1,any)); tb <- data.frame(sapply(f,tmpf)))` for readability/logic; it may be marginally slower than your solution ...

Comment: @BenBolker - you have one too many closing parens on the data.frame() call.